# Insert result from sql query into Array

Tags: java

I have a SQL query which returns array of integers. The question is what is the proper way to insert the integers into the array? Something like this:

```
int[] IntArray = new int[40];

            while (result.next())
            {

                IntArray[0] = result.getInt(1);
            }
```

The size of the array is always fixed. I get every tome 40 integers.

Comment: Is this not working? This is fine. Except maybe increment your array index every time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Indexed loop would do you good since you need to iterate through the index of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many rows your query is returning, then you should use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and its `add` method, which will grow past an initial size if necessary.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(40);
while (result.next())
{
    intArray.add(result.getInt(1));
}
```

If you need an array, then keep a counter variable and increment it each loop, so you don't overwrite the same first array element in each loop.

```
int[] intArray = new int[40];
int index = 0;
while (result.next())
{
    intArray[index] = result.getInt(1);
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need the **index** of the array as well.

```
int index=0;
  while (result.next())
 {
    IntArray[index] = result.getInt(1);
      index++;
 }
```